Clickhouse backup-restore explanations
Does anybody know how how backup-restore works inside the process?
I have table to backup which size is bigger then my avalible free space on clickhouse system directory, so I worr about being out of space during restoring data to table
Interested part is how data managing between copy and database, Does it transmited by parts or it moves whole copy?
So far not tried anything with it, not sure if it will work or break my instance

Do you mean BACKUP/RESTORE SQL commands or https://github.com/Altinity/clickhouse-backup/?
AFAIK
Embedded BACKUP SQL works following with steps:

data parts freeze to prevent from deletion it should allocate disk space only if you have massive data mutations in the same time
calculate increment on file level from base backup if necessary.
upload and compress if necessary data parts physically to destination Disk, File, S3, AzureBlobStorage.
If your table storage_policy contains object disks (S3,Azure) then will try to make remote service-side CopyObject without downloading data to local disks

Embedded RESTORE SQL works with following steps:

drop table if not RESTORE ... SETTINGS allow_non_empty_tables=1 it will free space from disk
download each data part one by one from backup remote storage into tmp_path (/var/lib/clickhouse/tmp/random_prefix/data/db/table/part_name/), if your storage policy contains object disk (s3, azure) then will try to server-side CopyObject to copy part content from backup to destination bucket from disk (small metadata will download in any case)
move downloaded files into /var/lib/clickhouse/data/db/table/part_name/ or /var/lib/clickhouse/store/prefix/uuid/part_name and register this part into part list in memory and register this new part into replication queue if destination table is Replicated*


No, this ones https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/operations/backup

I explained the internals of BACKUP/RESTORE in my answer
